# Difference between "from .checks import *" and "from . import checks"

Tags: python

I have a file called checks.py in my project.
I want to import everything at once.

Is there a difference between these two or is it just another way of writing it?

```
from .checks import *

from . import checks
```

Comment: Try accessing `checks.foo` one way or the other later on in the code, and you'll see *a* difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first one, to access a member of `checks`, simply type the member's name (because you are importing all members). e.g.

```
from .checks import *
foo(5) # foo is member of checks
```

In the second one, you are only importing `checks`, which means to access `foo`, you must write `checks.foo(5)` as opposed to just `foo(5)`.

Just a namespace thing, no big differences otherwise.

**EDIT:** As mentioned by @mata, typically in bigger projects `import`s with `*`s can get confusing, as you have no idea what module `foo` came from, and this is an even bigger problem if `foo` is a member of more than one module you are importing. Thus, importing using `*`s is considered bad practise.

Comment: Big difference is that if you have more then one `*` import you won't be able to easily tell where your `foo` came from. What if two modules have members with colliding names? For such reasons `*` imports are regarded as bad style.

Answer (score 1):

First, understand the meaning of the `from somewhere import something`, where `somewhere` refers to the directory where a certain package resides or the package itself, and `something` is a certain package or a feature from a particular package.

In your case, what you are trying to achieve is something called **relative import**. The `from .<module/package> import something` refers to a relative import. You can find more information on absolute and relative imports [here](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import).

Now, coming to your original question. Yes, there is a difference.

The `from .checks import *` statement will import all the classes/functions available inside the checks.py file. That is if your checks.py file contains a function named, let's say `foo`, then after executing this import statement you would be able to call `foo()` directly.

The `from . import checks` statement will import the module named checks. Hence, after executing this statement, you would be able to use/call any classes/function by following `<module>.<class/function>` notation. Therefore, in order to use `foo()` function, you have to use the syntax `checks.foo()`

**Note:** In both the cases, the file checks.py should be residing inside the current directory. The `.` refers to a relative path, in this case to the current directory.